# Check more ints in a range

Tags: java, range

Is there any simpler way to check more than one number in a range?
I have to check if three parameters of a method are in range 10 (inclusive) - 1000 (inclusive).
Can it be written nicer than this?

```
(x < 10) || (x > 1000) || (y < 10) || (y > 1000) || (z < 10) || (z > 1000)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

Like,

```
if (IntStream.of(x, y, z).anyMatch(a -> a < 10 || a > 1000))
```